# PHP - Custom Exception Message With Line Number

Tags: php, exception

Let's say I have a class that accepts an array of `SomeClass` when instantiated, for example:

```
class ConfigurableClass
{
    public function __construct( array $config = array() )
    {
        foreach( $config as $param )
        {
            if( !$param instanceof SomeClass )
            {
                $type = gettype($param);
                $line = ? // How can I retrieve this?
                throw new Exception("ConfigurableClass config parameters must be of type SomeClass, $type given in line $line");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

And let's say this class is instantiated **in a different file** with an array that has one element of the wrong type, for example:

```
$instance = new ConfigurableClass(array(
   new SomeClass(),
   new SomeClass(),
   new SomeClass(),
   'Ooops!',       // String type, line 5
   new SomeClass()
));
```

How can I throw an error message specifying the line number where the wrong object type was inserted?
In this case, the appropriate message should read:

```
"ConfigurableClass config parameters must be of type SomeClass, string given in line 4"
```

Keep in  mind that this is just an example. The real class can accept a very large and complicated array. Knowing the line number in that case can be very useful.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php but to handle your particular case, you'd probably need to work your way up the stack backtrace.

Comment: You shouldn't need this, just let the user know that they passed in an incorrect type, you could even give them which argument was incorrect by utilizing func_get_args http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: @ZachSpencer What if I want to make their life easier? Imagine that this class can accept very large configuration arrays, wouldn't it be useful then?

Comment: @MarcB, can you post an example?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: @MarcB I know what a debug backtrace is, the question is how can I combine it with predefined language constants to get the line number where the wrong parameter was set.

Comment: you can't, really, since the stack backtrace will only point at whichever line PHP considered as the "last" of that call. e.g. with your multiline call, the track will PROBABLY poitn at the `$istance = ..` line. But really, you shouldn't need to give people that much detail. is it really so bad to just say "invalid call at line X of file Y, 4th argument incorrect"? If your object's users are too stupid to count arguments themselves, they shouldn't be coding in the first place.

Comment: @MarcB What if this is a deep (e.g. more than 1 dimension) configuration array with 100 lines of code and various different objects? Would it still not be so bad to count the lines then?

Comment: Who writes an array more than 100 lines? Seriously. If he really wants to know what is the problem, he can use xdebug.

Answer (score 2):

the simplest maybe

```php
class MyException extends Exception {
  function __construct($message, $file, $line) {
    $this->file = $file;
    $this->line = $line;
  }
}

throw new MyException('error message', 'foo.php', 20220501);
```

Comment: Yes, I confirm, it is simple and it works well

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine the line (5 in your case) because it is given by the end of the caller instruction, that is, where the semicolon is located (7 in your case).

However you can get a good approximation by showing that line number and the wrong parameter number.

```
<?php
class ConfigurableClass
{
    public function __construct( array $config = array() )
    {
        $counter = 0;

        foreach( $config as $param )
        {
            if( !$param instanceof SomeClass )
            {
                $type = gettype($param);
                $line = debug_backtrace()[0]['line'];
                throw new Exception("ConfigurableClass config parameter[$counter] must be of type SomeClass, $type given in line $line");
            }

            $counter++;
        } 
    }
}
```

The message will be something like:

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'ConfigurableClass config parameter[3] must be of type SomeClass, string given in C:\your\folder\origin_file.php at line 12' in C:\your\folder\ConfigurableClass.php on line 15**

If, in the message, you want to avoid the reference to the ConfigurableClass file and line, you must to create your own derived exception class and overwrite the __toString() method.